# TYPO3 Formhandler Finisher_Mail multiple receivers with to_email + addTolist

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I have a formhandler-form and I'm trying to find a good way to send an admin mail to multiple recipients with one mail finisher. The Problem is the recipients are variable. The recipients of the mail depends on the selection of 10 checkboxes in the form. Each selection should have the effect that a new recipient is added. At the moment it's solved with 10 mail finisher like

```
if {
    1 {
        conditions {
            OR1.AND1 = checkbox_1 = 1
        }
        isTrue {
            finishers.1.config.admin.to_email = p1@mail.com
        }
        else {
            finishers.1.config.admin.disable = 1
        }
    }
    2 {
        conditions {
            OR1.AND1 = checkbox_2 = 1
        }
        isTrue {
            finishers.2.config.admin.to_email = p2@mail.com
        }
        else {
            finishers.2.config.admin.disable = 1
        }
    }
    ...
```

Is there a better way? I tried to solve this with one finisher and the usage of addToList

```
if {
    1 {
        conditions {
            OR1.AND1 = checkbox_1 = 1
        }
        isTrue {
            finishers.1.config.admin.to_email := addToList(p1@mail.com)
        }
    }
    2 {
        conditions {
            OR1.AND1 = checkbox_2 = 1
        }
        isTrue {
            finishers.1.config.admin.to_email := addToList(p2@mail.com)
        }
    }
    ...
```

But it doesn't work. With 4 selected boxes it is still one recipient. Why?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget: typoscript is a configuration language, no programming language.

so you need another logic to build up the multiple receivers.
something like:

```
:
finishers.1.config.admin.to_email = COA
finishers.1.config.admin.to_email {
    10 = TEXT
    10.value = p1@mail.com,
    10.if.isTrue.data = checkBox_1 

    20 = TEXT
    20.value = p2@mail.com,
    20.if.isTrue.data = checkBox_2

    30 = TEXT
    30.value = p3@mail.com,
    30.if.isTrue.data = checkBox_3 

    stdWrap.substring = 0,-1
}
```

Comment: ty for the help and the reminder that typoscript is not a programming language :) This is still a little bit confusing for me. I see if-clauses and think "oh yeah i can do everything like in other languages" But in reality it's very fixed and limited. 
The next problem is that I need some and-conjunctions inside of "isTrue". but there it is.. the limit of typoscript. Now I will build a little mapping-extension -_-

Comment: if you have multiple conditions which repeat you might use LOAD_REGISTER so the conditions don't need to be evaluated multiple times (also a big advantage in 'debugging')